# No data is printed out

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code in JavaScript that will store some floats, but I can't seem to get it to print out the correct data, here is a snippet of my code which is what im having problems with.

```
function Vector3(x,y,z){
    this.x = x; this.y = y; this.z = z;
}

function Edge(vec1, vec2){
    var vector1 = new Vector3(vec1.x,vec1.y,vec1.z);
    document.write(vector1.x+ "," +vector1.y +"," + vector1.z+"<br>");
var vector2 = new Vector3(vec2.x,vec2.y,vec2.z);
}

var sqrVer = new Array();
sqrVer[1] = new Vector3(-1.0,    1.0,    1.0);
sqrVer[2] = new Vector3( 1.0,    1.0,    1.0);
sqrVer[3] = new Vector3(-1.0,   -1.0,    1.0);
sqrVer[4] = new Vector3( 1.0,   -1.0,    1.0);
sqrVer[5] = new Vector3( 1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0);
sqrVer[6] = new Vector3( 1.0,    1.0,   -1.0);
sqrVer[7] = new Vector3(-1.0,    1.0,   -1.0);
sqrVer[8] = new Vector3(-1.0,   -1.0,   -1.0);

var sqrEdge = new Array();
sqrEdge[1] = new Edge(sqrVer[1], sqrVer[2]);


document.write(sqrVer[1].x + "<br>");
document.write(sqrEdge[1].vector1.x + "<br>");
```

Now what is printed out is this

```
-1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
-1.0
```

but for the line that goes to sqrEdge and tries to print out that x, nothing is written to screen??? why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Your Edge function isn't actually creating and returning anything.  This is causing your program to crash before it can print something out, because it returns an empty object (due to "new"), {}.vector1 = undefined and {}.vector1.x throws an error.

To fix this, try:

```
function Edge(vec1, vec2){
    this.vector1 = new Vector3(vec1.x,vec1.y,vec1.z);
    this.vector2 = new Vector3(vec2.x,vec2.y,vec2.z);
}
```

My advice would be to learn how to use one of the javascript consoles ("developer tools" in chrome or safari, or firebug in firefox).

This will show you when you have errors, and you can also use console.log() instead of document.write() which will let you send yourself messages without writing them into the page.

Comment: Cheers, i have just looked at it tells me that X cannot be read, why is this? i did give x a value?